# Count the total number of task on Lead as per the insert and delete?

Tags: apex, batch

Create a field on Lead called "number of task?" and run a batch class as per the number insert and delete the task records under lead record.
For example 1 lead have 6 in number of task  and tomorrow i will update to 8 then it should create 2 more task. Same time if I decrease then it should delete the Task Record.

Insert part I will done but delete part not yet.

Code:-

```java
global class BatchSample2 implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id, (SELECT id FROM Tasks) from Lead]);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Lead> leadList ){
        
        system.debug ('>>>>> Scope Size >>>>>' + leadList.size());
        
        for(Lead objLead : leadList){
            
            if(objLead.Tasks != null){
                
                system.debug ('>>>>> Scope Contact size Size >>>>>' + objLead.Tasks.size());
                
                objLead.Number_of_Task__c = objLead.Tasks.size();
            }
        }
        update leadList;
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure you want to do what you're describing.

It sounds like you want the value of the Number_of_Task__c field to control the child records, when really, you probably want a count of the number of child tasks controlled by creating/deleting the records themselves.

So basically you're creating a rollup summary where you can't declaratively put one. Fortunately, there is a lot out there on how to do this! But basically, the gist of it is: you would want to create an after trigger on both insert and delete of task. In that trigger, you can just count the number of tasks on the parent leads for the trigger records and update the field appropriately.